# matlab error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" with specific data file

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

I use the following code with different data files, without any problem. However, there is one file that creates troubles, and when I run the code with that file, I get an error:

'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'

I think that is because 'i' is equal to 2546, but when the code runs the line: `i=i+1`, instead of stopping at 2546, it keeps going and stops (giving the error) at 2547 - which of course exceeds the matrix dimensions. In fact, when the code stops working, producing the error, I can see in the Workspace that 'i' is equal to 2547, and 'j' to 2 (instead of 5, if the loop would have worked fine).

As the exact same code works perfectly fine with other files, I assume there is something to do with this specific file. Any insight on how to solve the issue?

Here is the code:

```
for i=1:size(colInd,1)
    for j=1:size(colInd,2)
        if colInd(i,j)>0 && colInd(i,j)<=13
            M1(i,j)=Windowsdata(i,colInd(i,j));
        elseif colInd(i,j)==0 | colInd(i,j)==14
            M1(i,j)=NaN;
        elseif colInd(i,j)==-1 | colInd(i,j)==15
            M1(i,:)=NaN;
            i=i+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Example lines from colInd, which is 2546 x 5 double

```
 4  5   6   7   8
-1  0   1   2   3
 2  3   4   5   6
11  12  13  14  15
 0  1   2   3   4
 5  6   7   8   9
 3  4   5   6   7
 5  6   7   8   9
-1  0   1   2   3
11  12  13  14  15
```

Example lines from Windowsdata, which is 2546 x 13 double

```
 -4.37370443344116  -1.64714550971985   0.569347918033600   1.62668454647064    3.73541021347046    5.15196514129639    4.04361486434937    1.77491927146912    0.702701866626740   -0.354207783937454  1.18695282936096    2.82701897621155    4.01644039154053
  3.72757863998413  1.44241857528687    -1.15181946754456   -2.97936320304871   -5.16328191757202   -4.25508642196655   -2.47518587112427   0.287524074316025   -1.17596077919006   -2.04023623466492   -2.78539514541626   -2.96725606918335   -5.59557294845581
 -5.52127933502197  -1.69257545471191   3.61181259155273    4.46472501754761    0.345008432865143   -4.78608989715576   -7.80892658233643   -8.83082866668701   -5.61083126068115   -4.40270948410034   -3.05102157592773   -4.67261123657227   -5.50971889495850
  1.24733197689056  0.692575275897980   0.549045324325562   1.33569169044495    2.26527953147888    3.19271230697632    1.92626762390137    -0.00543282041326165    -1.76812970638275   -3.55482935905457   -2.28071475028992   2.58129334449768    6.07476711273193
  2.17950797080994  2.73428583145142    1.63492679595947    -0.256836771965027  -0.773400425910950  -1.04227805137634   -1.82435607910156   -2.64025163650513   -1.53338134288788   -2.29410648345947   -4.26442241668701   -4.76120758056641   -4.47712421417236
 -0.246993020176888 0.157185763120651   0.250829964876175   -0.986824631690979  1.40918886661530    5.03370332717896    8.15515422821045    6.41663646697998    2.43448591232300    -2.98093175888062   -3.53510475158691   -1.89243125915527   1.47953033447266
  4.36318445205688  5.06837177276611    5.78645181655884    6.97499608993530    7.49895095825195    5.27076244354248    4.75153970718384    4.35132837295532    2.37539553642273    0.0745598822832108  0.782306909561157   1.98255372047424    1.82295107841492
  0.393009424209595 0.348423480987549   -0.0242169145494699 -0.451373100280762  0.792472958564758   3.95410203933716    6.95971775054932    6.07247447967529    4.61793804168701    2.25326156616211    1.17793440818787    -1.02191674709320   -1.40514099597931
  2.97367334365845  2.56695508956909    -0.0324615947902203 -0.512259364128113  -0.169182881712914  1.99416732788086    2.05820631980896    1.26427924633026    -0.107465483248234  -1.26579785346985   -2.51656532287598   -2.19553661346436   -1.86673855781555
 -5.92374515533447  -4.78130531311035   -5.02523994445801   -4.12971973419189   -2.56698751449585   -2.16855669021606   -2.66882371902466   -3.24165868759155   -4.10617780685425   -4.71752023696899   -4.63748264312744   -3.33325529098511   -2.00388121604919
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* error message and a [mcve].

Comment: the full error message is as I reported `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`. No line is stated that I can report, or refer to.

Comment: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` is the only thing in your command window? What is `Windowsdata`? How does it relate to `colInd`? Please see the "Complete" part of the linked help page above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `colInd` is a `NxM` matrix with `N=2546` and you have the expectation, that in your last elseif, by incrementing `i` by one you end up in the next outer for loop iteration, starting `j` from `1` to `M` in the `(i+1)th` iteration.

If this is the behaviour you want to achieve, you need to use the `break` statement to break out of the inner for loop. Else, if `j<size(colInd,2)`, `j` will be incremented and the inner loop continues.

If I understood your desired behaviour correctly, it is not a problem with the file, but rather of your algorithm. But as @excaza pointed out, you should really give an example that is mcve, including the necessary variables (such as Windowsdata). Otherwise it is really difficult to make sense of what you're trying to do.

Edit: Give this a try:

```
for i=1:size(colInd,1)
    for j=1:size(colInd,2)
        if colInd(i,j)>0 && colInd(i,j)<=13
            M1(i,j)=Windowsdata(i,colInd(i,j));
        elseif colInd(i,j)==0 | colInd(i,j)==14
            M1(i,j)=NaN;
        elseif colInd(i,j)==-1 | colInd(i,j)==15
            M1(i,:)=NaN;
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

Edit2: To clarify: The problem you describe occurs if in the iteration where `i=size(colInd,1)` (i.e. `i=2546`) and `j<size(colInd,2)` (i.e. `j<5`, let's assume `j=1` for simplicity) the last `elseif` holds. Thus, causing your `i` to be incremented to `i=2546+1=2547`, and the inner loop goes through the next iteration. With `j=2` now, in the first if you attempt to access `colInd(2547,2)`, which exceeds the dimensions of `colInd`.

Edit3: If you want a more Matlab-y implementation for this, because for loops are not very good Matlab coding style, I also append this solution that uses vectorization (albeit not that great).

```
colInd = [ 4  5   6   7   8;
-1  0   1   2   3;
 2  3   4   5   6;
11  12  13  14  15;
 0  1   2   3   4;
 5  6   7   8   9;
 3  4   5   6   7;
 5  6   7   8   9;
-1  0   1   2   3;
11  12  13  14  15;
10  11  12  13  14];

Windowsdata = reshape([1:size(colInd,1)*13],[size(colInd,1) 13]);

M1 = zeros(size(colInd));
M2 = zeros(size(colInd));

c1 = find(colInd>0&colInd<=13);
c2 = find(colInd==0|colInd==14);
c3 = find(colInd==-1|colInd==15);
[x1,~] = ind2sub(size(colInd),c1);
[x3,~] = ind2sub(size(colInd),c3);

M2(c1) = Windowsdata(sub2ind(size(Windowsdata),x1,colInd(c1)));
M2(c2) = NaN;
M2(x3,:) = NaN;
```

It runs about 3-5 times as fast as your for loop implementation.

Edit: Added the missing term to the sub2ind call, and it gives the same result as the for loop:

```
M1 =
 34    45    56    67    78
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 14    25    36    47    58
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN     5    16    27    38
 50    61    72    83    94
 29    40    51    62    73
 52    63    74    85    96
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
110   121   132   143   NaN

M2 =
 34    45    56    67    78
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 14    25    36    47    58
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN     5    16    27    38
 50    61    72    83    94
 29    40    51    62    73
 52    63    74    85    96
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
110   121   132   143   NaN
```

Comment: Adding `break` I don't get the error, however, when that section is run and completed, `i` is still equal to 2547, and `j` is now equal to 1, suggesting that the code stops at the first loop, and it didn't run for loop from 2 to 5. Or maybe, this is what you wanted to check?

Comment: It's clear that `i=2547`, because you incremented `i` by one in the inner loop in the last elseif. It appears I misunderstood your expected behaviour of the algorithm, because you didn't properly describe, what you want it to do. If you can give a toy example that shows the case where your algorithm fails and you describe the behaviour you *expected* from the algorithm, that would help tremendously.

Comment: Please see the explanation I added below my initial answer.

Comment: What I need the algorithm to do is to find the value in Windowsdata that corresponds to the index in colInd. However, if any cell of each row (in colInd) is equal to zero, or to 14, I want to replace that particular cell (but not the entire row) with NaN.
If any cell of each row (in colInd) is equal to -1 or to 15, I want NaN for that entire row. When I run the code that generates the error, it works in terms of what the algorithm does, but it stops.

Comment: I wonder why it always worked, except for this particular file.

Comment: It appears that your `colInd` vector is strictly increasing in the second dimension. That means the error can only occur, if the *last* row contains an element equal to `-1` (and since it's strictly increasing in the second dimension this can only occur as the first element), or similarly, if any element before the fifth element in the last row is equal to `15`. And it is an error of your implementation rather than an error of the data. Your algorithm isn't doing exactly what it should be doing. Use a small toy example and observe the behaviour with the debugging tool.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation! I am not sure how to change the code though.

Comment: Sorry, I had a bit of a brainfart there. I fixed the code in my original post. By removing the `i=i+1;` the `break;` command achieves exactly the same thing. It moves to the next iteration in the outer for loop by ending the inner one. Sorry for that mishap. This should be exactly how you want it to function. Please take a look at the [break](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html?s_tid=srchtitle) and [continue](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html) reference in the MathWorks Documentation.

Comment: I also added an alternative solution to your problem that avoids the for loops entirely. See bottom of my original answer.

Comment: Thank you Franz for the alternative solutions. However, for the solution without loops, when there is a zero or 14 in one cell of the rows, the entire rows become NaN,rather than only that single cell. Regarding the `break` and `continue`, I have read the Matlab Documentation, but I still don't understand how to use them in this context. If I only use `break` immediately after `M1(i,:)=NaN;`, the code stops working after running the first loop. How should I get running from the 2nd to the fifth loop? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you have the following line at some random `i`: `-1  0   1   2   3`. At `j=1` the third `elseif` holds, and thus makes the entire line of `M1(i,:)=NaN`. You can then terminate looking at `j=2:5`, so you `break;` out. Next iteration will do `i=i+1` and start at `j=1:5` again. This is exactly what you wanted, or am I misunderstanding? You make it really difficult to understand what your really simple algorithm should be doing.

Comment: If you have this line as colInd: `colInd = [-1  0   1   2   3;  2  3   4   5   6; -1  0   1   2   3];` with `Windowsdata=ones(size(colInd));`. Please tell me exactly what you expect to be in `M1` after your algorithm finished. Otherwise I have to give up trying to help you because I just don't understand what's supposed to be going on.